# Why is the ExceptionTranslator for CqlTemplate null (impl class for CqlOperations)?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I have a class annotated with `@Repository` that I am using as a dao for cassandra.  It is autowired with an instance of `CassandraOperations`

```
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

{ // some method...
    cassandraOperations.query(...);
    ...
}
```

Occasionally I am getting a datastax ReadTimeOutException, which is a RuntimeException, when I query using the field.  When CqlTemplate.java (the spring impl class for `CassandraOperations`) attempts to call `translateExceptionIfPossible` it uses a field called `exceptionTranslator`, which is not being set by the spring injector.  This causes a null pointer exception to be thrown, instead of the ReadTimeOutException.  Why is this field not being properly set?

It cant be something I need to set, as the set method is only on the impl class, and not on any of the interfaces in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this.  One liner fix, surprised we hadn't seen it before!  :)

I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-159 and pushed a fix in both the 1.0.x (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/commit/21c3d06988c80b876ec374c1ebf4b36a525fb4d5) & master (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/commit/f921553fb54598639f7b6e6f10ad0b8919bc0a80) branches.

If you need it, use 1.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.  Both should be available soon.

-matthew